# onClick is getting triggerd multiple times react ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, react-query

I have a download functionality where I am downloading

```
const csvLink = createRef();

const dropdown = (
  <div onClick={refetch}>
    {safeLabel(messages.csv)}
    <Icon name="pull" />
    {isSuccess ? <CSVLink ref={csvLink} data={data?.data}></CSVLink> : null}
  </div>
);

const onsuccess = (response) => {
  csvLink?.current?.link?.click();
};

const { refetch, data, isSuccess } = useQuery(
  "apicall",
  () => fetchData(headers),
  {
    enabled: false,
    onSuccess: onsuccess
  }
);
```

So, here when I click on the icon pull that time query gets called and sends me a response which I am passing it to the `csvLink`  and trying to download the csv. Now because of the `csvLink?.current?.link?.click();` called in onsuccess of query this `refetch` is getting called in infinite loop. Where to call this click and how to fix this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: based on your code the `csvDownloadSuccess` is called `onSuccess`. shouldn't it be like this?
` const { refetch, data, isSuccess } = useQuery(  
        'apicall',
        () => fetchData(headers),
        {
          enabled: false,
          onSuccess: onSuccess,
          
        },
      );`

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in question , editing it.

Comment: @Cid updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **useRef** instead of **createRef**

```
const csvLink = useRef();
```

createRef: function creates a new ref every re-render.

useRef: function uses the same ref throughout. It saves it's value between re-renders in a functional component and doesn't create a new instance of the ref for every re-render.